# SAS PROC CORR output

Tags: sas, proc

In SAS proc corr, I want the output to show only Pearson Correlation Coefficient. 
By default, the output also shows the following :- Prob > |r| under H0: Rho=0 and Number of observations. How do I do this? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would output a dataset and then `proc print` or report or whatnot that dataset.

```
proc corr data=sashelp.class out=corrcoeff(where=(_type_='CORR');
 var age height weight;
run;
```